# Is there a widget for Ubuntu 14.04 that monitors RAM, processor, hdd/ssd, LAN, etc?

Tags: desktop-environments, process, widgets, modem-manager, gnome-power-manager

I been using a process manager and it's ok but I was wondering if there is a desktop widget I could use, that doesn't cost me much RAM to use.

Comment: @Robby1212 it says **desktop** widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conky is worth looking at, it floats on your desktop, behind all the windows you have open.  Very customisable, which is great for experienced users but a little intimidating.

have a look at this guide to get started
https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-and-configure-conky